# 48VAC analog waveform

Tags: analog, circuit-design

I want to make a circuit to drive out a 48VAC 10mA 60Hz sine wave signal.
 I was thinking that I could generate a waveform with a microcontroller to feed it to an opamp then to a audio transformer
 Would this work? 
I wanted it to he handheld, so I was thinking about sourcing the circuit with a battery. Haven't thought to much about the size.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Thank you for sharing your thoughts but you need to ask a specific electrical design question rather than look for a free design service. Describe in more how you think you can achieve this and where you are stuck on the design. You have omitted frequency of the waveform. Also some context would be useful so we can comment on whether this is the right solution to the real problem. Put all the info into the question using the edit link. Oh, and what's the waveform? Sine, square, triangle, sawtooth?

Comment: You can find opamps that support unusually high voltage outputs and support your required current compliance, as well (not so easy); you can use regular opamps for the purpose and then use a final stage to provide voltage amplification and the current compliance; or else you can do this with a microcontroller followed by an appropriate low-pass filter, level shift (DC block) perhaps, and then a final stage to provide voltage amplification and current compliance.

Comment: Such approach can be viable.

Comment: How precise do your voltage, current and frequency need to be? Does the sine-wave need to be clean, or can it have some mild distortion?

Comment: No. The output doesn't need to be very clean. There can be some mild distortions.

Comment: @jonk such op-amps do exist.  But this is probably not the best way to solve the problem unless the question has strict constraints yet unmentioned by the asker.

Comment: @T-C this type of question can have too many solutions, and picking the best is not really possible without knowing what you are trying to do.  Please describe the *purpose* of this output so that the community can deduce requirements you are unaware of, and also fully explain any constraints or requirements already known to you.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Agreed. Note I did say, "not so easy," with respect to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking a broad question, so here are some broad comments in response.

You have a load of approximately 4800 Ω and you want to drive about 480 mW into it. Sounds reasonable.

You can easily get low-cost prebuilt modules to do both functions: DDS modules will synthesize your sine wave, and audio amplifier modules can provide the needed power level.

The only detail is that audio power amplifier modules are generally designed for low output impedances (in the range of 4 to 16 Ω or so). An easy way do deal with this mismatch is to use a transformer.

A small power transformer with a 24:1 voltage ratio will provide approximately the 600:1 (\$\frac{4800 \Omega}{8 \Omega}\$) impedance ratio you need. For example, if you can find one with a 120V primary and a 5V secondary, you'd be all set — just hook it up in reverse. A commonly-available 6.3V transformer would probably be close enough; just turn the gain on the amplifier up a bit.

An audio transformer with the required impedance ratio would also work, but would probably be less efficient at 60 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an ordinary power transformer? You need a turns ratio of 120/48 or 2.5:1. The power level is very low so almost any transformer intended for 60 Hz use will do.

Comment: Did you miss the point about battery operation?

Comment: @Dave He said he was thinking about using a battery, not that it was a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a prototype I made years ago. It generates up to 30V 20mA sine wave with adjustable frequency and amplitude. Unfortunately it did not scale well to 110VAC I needed, so it was abandoned. But otherwise it worked great and I believe it can be easily scaled up to 48V. Discard instrumentation amplifier and connect something like OPA548 in differential configuration directly to sine outputs. Use another OPA548 with -1 gain on the first output to generate mirrored output.

[image]

The whole thing, including ATmega328 and Recom DC-DC for output stage was powered by 9V battery.

Comment: A TDA2003  or alike would be the right candidate to beef it up.

Comment: @carloc it is nowhere close to required 48V and it is a single rail amplifier.

Comment: I just meant to use it in the 9V powered circuit above. An transformer will then step voltage up to what required.

Comment: Ah, yes. The output of AD9834 can be fed directly into OP amp powered from the battery and then stepped up by a transformer. But that would be completely different circuit then. And it won't be nice because of DC offset flowing through the primary.